# URL Structure for Comparing Items

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-5

What is the best way to structure a route for comparing multiple items?

Here's the URL example: https://versus.com/en/microsoft-teams-vs-slack-vs-somalia

How to achieve this in routes.rb file? Cannot really find anything in Internet regarding ruby gems. The only thing I can think about is url with optional params, however what if the number of params is unlimited?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First - you probably shouldn't allow unlimited #'s of parameters in practice. Even something like 100 might break your page and/or cause performance issues and open you up to DOS attacks. I'd choose some kind of sensible/practical limit and document/enforce it (like 10, 12 or whatever makes sense for your application). At around 2k characters you'll start running into [URL-length issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers).

Next - is there any flexibility in the URL? Names tend to change so if you want URL's to work over time you'll need to slug-ify each of them (with something like [friendly-id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id)) so you can track changes over time. For example - could you use an immutable/unique ID AND human-readable names?

In any case, Rails provides a very flexible system for URL routing.  You can read more about the various options / configurations with their [Rails routing documentation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v6.0/routing.html).

By default a [Dynamic Segment](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v6.0/routing.html#dynamic-segments) supports text like in your example, so (depending on your controller name) you can do something like:

```rb
get 'en/:items', to: 'items#compare'
```

If it's helpful you can add a custom `constraint` regexp to guarantee that the parameter looks like what you expect (e.g. `word-with-dashes-vs-another-vs-something-else`)

```rb
get 'en/:items', to: 'items#compare', constraints: { items: /(?:(?:[A-Z-]+)vs)+(?:[A-Z-]+)/ }
```

Then, in your controller, you can parse out the separate strings however you want. Something like...

```rb
  def compare
    items = params[:items].split('-vs-')
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

you're going to have to parse the `a-vs-b-vs-c` yourself.

So in routes.rb, you'll have something like:

```rb
get 'compare/:compare_string', to 'compare#show'
```

then you'll get a parameter `compare_string` that you'll have to parse:

```rb
#in compare_controller.rb

def show
  compare_items = params[:compare_string].split('-vs-')

  # generate the comparison from the compare_items array
end
```

Comment: i think that make sense. thank you for you feedback! i will try it!